# how to combine 2 selectors in ngrx effect

Tags: ngrx, state-management

here's the scenario. i have this 2 different selectors which compose of different properties. what i want to happen is to combine them together which will be later on to be used as a parameters:

here's the codes:

```
 @Injectable()
export class AuthenticationEffect {
    getJwtToken$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(TransactionIDActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS),
            concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(withLatestFrom(
                this.store.select(getTransactionIDSelector),
                this.store.select(getAuthPayload)
            ))),
            mergeMap(([, transactionId, authPayload]) => {
                return this.authenticationService.getJwtToken(this.AuthenticateRequest(transactionId)).pipe(
                    map(response => {
                        return LoadSessionSuccess(response);
                    }),
                    catchError(error => of(LoadSessionError(error)))
                );
            })
        );
    });

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private store: Store<any>, private authenticationService: AuthenticateService) {}

    AuthenticateRequest(transactionId): AuthenticateInterface {
        return {
            transactionId,
            sourceIdentifier,
            residentType,
            organizationCode,
            profile,
            kycId,
            identificationNumber,
            mobileIdentifier,
            nationality,
            dateAcceptedTermsOfUse,
        };
    }
}
```

i need to execute this two selectors

this.store.select(getTransactionIDSelector),
this.store.select(getAuthPayload)

at the same time, is this possible? and how do i get the state value for each selectors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concatLatestFrom` for this (instead of `concatMap` in combination with `withLatestFrom`).

```
...
concatLatestFrom(() => [
      this.store.select(getTransactionIDSelector),
      this.store.select(getAuthPayload)
]),
...
```